# Bootstrap Sidebar on Laravel 5 specific page only

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade, sidebar

I'm pretty new to bootstrap and I'm making a Laravel App. and I just want to make a left sidebar on my page. I don't want to edit the `app.blade.php` because I don't want to make the sidebar on all pages, just on this specific page. This is my code:

[my code](http://pastebin.com/CDrRZiDX)

And my page looks like [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Request::url() == url() . '/your/url/goes/here')
    @include('whatever-you-wish-here')
@endif
```

This will go in a base view that all other views extend.

So in your case I assume `app.blade.php`

Comment: Sir thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the confusion on my quesion but I need the code or how can I make the sidebar coz I'm not that familiar yet with bootstrap. thanks

Comment: Ah well that's a whole different story. I guess this is a good place to start http://bootswatch.com/ . Lots of different free templates.